# Label inside UICollectioviewCell taking frame after scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using collectionView in my app.
I have label inside my collectionViewCell.

I want to set frame to that label.

My code is:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {
   menuCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.lblTag.frame = cell.contentView.frame;
   cell.lblTag.text = [arrMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   return cell;
}
```

But this frame is works after i scroll collection view.
how can i reload collection view so that label frame set when collectionView display.

Comment: i am setting label frame according to text.
because text is dynamic so.

Comment: yes i know that.
i am just finding problem why frame setting after scroll.

Comment: balkaran singh's answer solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can reload the collection view in viewDidAppear

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [self.yourcollectionView_outLet reloadData];
}
```

in my case it work for me.

you can try to change frame in main queue

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           cell.lblTag.frame = cell.contentView.frame;
        });
```

Comment: i tried but still it set frame to label after scroll only.

Comment: are you using autolayout  ?

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya use dispatch_async to change the frame.

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya  Great           :)